# R-Text mining: replace abbreviations, numbers and symbols in german

Tags: r, replace, numbers, text-mining, abbreviation

I would like to replace the abbreviations, numbers and symbols in my text.
As my text is in german and not in english I have problems in converting it.

I tried:

```
review_text <- replace_abbreviation(review_text)

review_text <- replace_number(review_text)

review_text <- replace_symbol(review_text)
```

But this works just for an English text and not for German.
What should I add that the function also works in German?

Comment: From the documentation, the package seems to be build around the english language. So without looking further into the package it seems like the necessary steps would be to extend the package for an entirely new language. (Disclaimer, i have no experience with the `qdap` package myself)

Answer (score 0):

qdap and qdap related packages are solely for use with the English language. If you want to use German text with ümlauts and everything, packages like quanteda and udpipe can handle this. But they do not handle abbreviations and symbols. Now the `replace_symbol` function is easy to adjust, just inspect the function, copy the code to create your own function and replace the English translations with the German translations.

The `replace_abbreviation` function points to a replacement table where the abbreviation are stored with the corresponding value. You need to create your own table for German.

The biggest issue is translating the numbers to text. This is different for each language is not really available online. Searching for this tends to lead to converting numbers to text in excel. But if you can read python, you can translate a python function to R (or use reticulate) to solve this. See [this link](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words) to a python library on Github which can do this for a few languages including German. But I'm not sure if this can be used in a text mining context.